# Count no. of ways with exactly K turns

Tags: combinatorics

Given two distinct points A(P,Q) and B(R,S) with P,Q,R,S>=0. What is the number of ways to count paths with exactly K turns given that we can move in only two directions i.e. right and down?

My approach:I first counted total number of rights and downs required to move from point A to B.The number of rights is given by R-P.Similarly total number of downs is given by S-Q.

For only one turn answer is 2.

For only two turns answer is (R-P)+(S-Q).

But I'm not able to derive a general formula? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: IF your points are given on a plane and you are free to choose the initial direction and the turning points ;) then there's continuum of such paths for each given numer of turns $n > 0$ and only one path for $n=0$. However there are 2 paths for $n=0$ on a sphere if $A,B$ are not antipodes and countably many paths on a cylinder (provided $A,B$ are not in same plane perpendicular to the cylinder's axis)...

Comment: I don't think your answer for 2 turn is correct. After the first turn, you have no choice of going all the way before turning again. Hence the number of possibility is just the number of first choice, which is $R-P$ when going right initially, and $S-Q$ when going down initially, sum up to a total of $R-P+S-Q$

Comment: @CiaPan: I believe that these type of question assume that you are moving on some sort of grid, and have to move in step by $1$. That's just a convention, otherwise almost all problem will have the boring answer of $2^{\aleph_{0}}$.

Comment: @Gina:Thanks for pointing out this mistake

Comment: @Gina Yes, me too. But on first glance I've not found the info within initial assumptions and somehow missed the appended explanation *'we can move in only two directions i.e. right and down'*. When found it, just added a smiley to my own assumptions, which were much more general than in original problem.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot another thing. For $K=2$ you cannot decide to make the first turn all the way at the end (eg. go right $R-P$ amount and then make the turn), as you won't have no room left for the second turn. The answer for $K=2$ should be $R-P+S-Q-2$. I also fixed my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to notice that this is just the disguised combinatorial choice with repetition problem. That is, if we denote $m$ to be the amount you can go down, and $n$ to be the amount you can go right, then the choice of when you turn with respect to $m$ and when you turn with respect $n$ is independent. For example, if $K=2$, then if you started out going down, then you basically are partitioning $m$ into $2$ parts, and $n$ into $1$ part. If we set $r=\lfloor\frac{K}{2}\rfloor+1$ then $r$ is the number of partition allowed for the side we initially go the same direction in.

Hence the answer is simply:

For $K$ odd, $2\begin{pmatrix}m-1\\m-r\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}n-1\\n-r\end{pmatrix}$

For $K$ even, $\begin{pmatrix}m-1\\m-r\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}n-1\\n-r+1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}m-1\\m-r+1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}n-1\\n-r\end{pmatrix}$